# How to get all params after the root path

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

My app runs under `root`. I wanted to extract any text after `root`.

In the below URL, I wanted to extract `/a1/b1`.

```
http://localhost:4200/root/a1/b1
```

Below is my code,

```
this.route.params.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(params => {
  this.urlText = params.ID;
});
```

This is giving me only `/a1`

Comment: You can try something like this: `this.urlText = this.route.url.split("root")[1];`

Comment: i get this error `Property 'split' does not exist on type 'Observable<UrlSegment[]>'.ts(2339)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `this.router` where `router` is of type `Router`.

Comment: This seems to working fine

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have declared the name of params in the angular route file. So you can just import route from @angular/router and use this.route.snapshot.params["paramName"].

for example
if your route is

```
'localhost4200/:root/:a1/:b1'
```

in your component file import route and declare it in constructor like private route: Router and in ngOnInit use

```
this.route.snapshot.params["a1"]
this.route.snapshot.params["b1"]
```

this will get the job done

Comment: it can be /a1/b1/c1 and so on...Each time I don;t want to repeat those lines

Comment: I wanted to get the consolidated params